# PowerShell script to copy filtered data in Excel to another sheet

Tags: excel, powershell

I am new to PowerShell. I have a file name as Input.xlsx file, which will contain 3 columns and we an filter on any column and save it.

My requirement is to copy the filtered data in another sheet using PowerShell.

[image]

I wrote this using VBA and it's working, but I need to do same thing using PowerShell.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Importe()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    lastRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).End(xlDown).Row

    Worksheets.Add

    With ActiveSheet
       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:B" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Range("B1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:C" & lastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
       .Range("C1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

       
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: look for the excel modules avaiable for powershell https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/introducing-the-powershell-excel-module-2/

Comment: can you help me, i am not able to find anything?

Comment: I need to read filtered data from excel sheet.